# Changing CSS properties of a heading when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, click

What I am attempting to do is highlight the border of the box which has been clicked in a different colour when selected. I have tried to use classes in the typescript file by using document.getElementById in the selectFlight method(which is called in the flight-viewer.html using (click) shown here:

flight.viewer.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'flight-viewer',
    templateUrl: 'app/flight-viewer.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/flight-viewer.css']
})
export class FlightViewerComponent  {
    name = 'FlightViewerComponent';
    errorMessage = "";
    stateValid = true;
    flights: Flight[];
    selectedFlight: Flight;
    flightToUpdate: Flight;
    flightClicked = false;
    @Output()
    onFlightUpdating = new EventEmitter<Flight>();

    constructor(private service: FlightService) {
        this.selectedFlight = null;
        this.flightToUpdate = null;
        this.fetchFlights();
    }

    flightSelected(selected: Flight) {
        console.log("Setting selected flight to: ", selected.number);
        this.selectedFlight = selected;
    }
    flightUpdating(selected: Flight) {
        console.log("Setting updateable flight to: ", selected.number);
        this.flightToUpdate = selected;
    }

    updateFlight() {
        console.log("Just selected ", this.selectedFlight.number, " for update");
        this.onFlightUpdating.emit(this.selectedFlight);
    }

    selectFlight(selected: Flight) {
    console.log("Just click on this flight ", selected.number, " for display");
   this.flightClicked = true;
   this.selectedFlight = selected;
    // add 'active' class
    alert(document.getElementById("getFlight"));
    document.getElementById("getFlight").className = "active";
}

    private fetchFlights() {
        this.selectedFlight = null;
        this.flightToUpdate = null;
        this.service
            .fetchFlights()
            .subscribe(flights => this.flights = flights,
                       () => this.raiseError("No flights found!"));
    }
}
```

Flight-viewer.html

```
<h3>Flights </h3>
<div >
    <ul class= "grid grid-pad">
        <a *ngFor="let flight of flights" class="col-1-4">
        <li class ="module flight" (click)="selectFlight(flight)" id="getFlight">
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{flight.number}}</h4>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="box" *ngIf="flightClicked">
    <!--<flight-selected [flight]="selectedFlight"></flight-selected>-->
          You have selected flight: {{selectedFlight.number}}<br>
          From: {{selectedFlight.origin}}<br>
          Leaving at: {{selectedFlight.departure || date }}<br>
          Going to: {{selectedFlight.destination}}<br>
          Arriving at: {{selectedFlight.arrival || date}}<br><br>
    <h3><span (click)="updateFlight(flight)">Update</span></h3>

</div>

<div *ngIf="flightToUpdate">
    <flight-update [flight]="flightToUpdate"
                   (onFlightUpdated)="updateFlight($event)"></flight-update>
</div>
```

flight-viewer.css:

```
   h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h4:focus {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 120px;
    min-width: 170px;
    background-color:limegreen;
}

ul {
    width: 1600px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background: #ccc;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
div
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* if you need ie7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}

.module {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #eee;
    max-height: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
    background-color: #607D8B;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.active {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #eee;
    max-height: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
    background-color: #607D8B;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 5px solid #73AD21

}

.normal {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #eee;
    max-height: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
    background-color: #607D8B;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.module:hover {
    background-color: #EEE;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #607d8b;
}

.box {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 180px;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #73AD21;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Basically, I want the .module to have a different border colour when it has been clicked. I tried to implement this with the .active and .normal classes referred to in the component class but this is not working.

What my app looks like:
[image]

Basically, I want the whole box which is highlighted in grey to have a different border colour, rather than just a small rectangle within the box to have a different border colour.(I achieved this using tab index but its not suffice)

I would appreciate any help on this. Cheers.

EDIT: It now highlights the box but when I close the alert box it goes away. How do I make it so that the green outline stays until I click a different box? Cheers

[image]

Comment: there is no element with module id...How will this document.getElementById("module").className = "active"; work ??

Comment: @jANVI in the html, the line: <li class ="module flight" (click)="selectFlight(flight)">
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{flight.number}}</h4>
            </li>

Comment: then in the css file when I change properties of module { } it alters the box around each flight number.. @jANVI

Comment: First try to alert this in your selectFlight function and check if it is returning any element or null  ; document.getElementById("module");

Comment: it does not return any element, returns null. What way do i reference it then?

Comment: Posted answer..plz chk

Answer (score 1):

You have written like :

```
document.getElementById("module").className = "active";
```

There is no element in the HTML provided with id = **"module"**

//Replace this :

```
 <li class ="module flight" (click)="selectFlight(flight)">
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{flight.number}}</h4>
            </li>
```

With

```
<li class ="module flight" (click)="selectFlight(flight)" id="getFlight">
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{flight.number}}</h4>    </li>
```

Then try :

```
 document.getElementById("getFlight").className = "active";
```

Comment: I have updated my code in the original post & included what you have posted, it works but when I close the alert box, the border of the highlighted box that has been click disappears. therefore it is only temporary until the ok button on the alert has been clicked. any ideas?? thanks

Comment: where are you using alert in your code? There is no alert in the code posted

Comment: apologies. Updated - in the selectFlight method

Comment: Correct your css classes remove this .module:active {
    border: 5px solid #73AD21;
} and add valid color here  border-color: deeppink;

Comment: in .active class add this  border: 5px solid #73AD21; instead of  border-color: deeppink

Comment: still the same - appears temporarily then when i click ok on the alert the border is no longer there

Comment: please update your css so that I can see the changes that you have made

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to "add" the new class simply replaces all classes of the `.module` element with `active`

I guess you would like to do something like

```
// add 'active' class
document.getElementById("module").className = document.getElementById("module").className + " active";

// remove 'active' class
document.getElementById("module").className = document.getElementById("module").className.replace('active','');
```

Comment: i replaced the line in my component in the selectFlight() method : document.getElementById("module").className = "active"; with 
// add 'active' class
document.getElementById("module").className = document.getElementById("module").className + " active";

and the border doesn't change upon clicking the box? @simne7

Comment: As far as I see there is no id named "module" in your HTML code => the `document.getElementById("module")` doesn't work. The ID of the `<li>` element is "getFlight". Maybe you could provide a jsfiddle code example or something else in order to make it easier for us to help you.